# Bootstrap drop down panel not working in Windows 10

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am making drop down panel using bootstrap but it is not working in windows 10.It looks every thing ok but still the drop down panel is not working.
Here is Code given below to help me to identify where is the problem.

```
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    </head>
<body>
     <div class="modal-body">
   <form id="adForm" method="" class="form-horizontal" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="panel-group" id="adSteps">
                    <!-- Step 1 Ad information -->
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#adSteps" href="#stepOneAdInfo">Ad Info</a></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="stepOneAdInfo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="adTitle">Title</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="adTilte" name="adTitle" placeholder=" Title...">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="adDescription">Description</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="adDescription" name="adDescription" placeholder=" Ads with good description are more likely to get buyer's attention..."></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="adCatagory">Catagory</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <select class="form-control" id="adCatagory" name="adCatagory">
                                        <option></option>
                                        <option>CatagoryA</option>
                                        <option>CatagoryB</option>
                                        <option>CatagoryC</option>
                                    </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="adSubCatagory">Sub Catagory</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <select class="form-control" id="adSubCatagory" name="adSubCatagory">
                                        <option></option>
                                        <option>SubCatagoryA</option>
                                        <option>SubCatagoryB</option>
                                        <option>SubCatagoryC</option>
                                    </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="adLocation">Location</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <select class="form-control" id="adLocation" name="adLocation">
                                        <option>Rawalpindi</option>
                                        <option>Islamabad</option>
                                        <option>Kahuta</option>
                                        <option>Humak</option>
                                    </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="adPrice">Price</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="adPrice" name="adPrice" placeholder=" Price in PKR...">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Step 2 Ad Images -->
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#adSteps" href="#stepTwoAdImages">Ad Images</a></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="stepTwoAdImages" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/adImageDefault.png" alt="Chania" id="adImageContainer1">
                                            <input type="file" id="adImage1" style="display:none;" name="adPhoto1">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/adImageDefault.png" alt="Chania" id="adImageContainer2">
                                            <input type="file" id="adImage2" style="display:none;" name="adPhoto2">
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/adImageDefault.png" alt="Chania" id="adImageContainer3"> 
                                            <input type="file" id="adImage3" style="display:none;" name="adPhoto3">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/adImageDefault.png" alt="Chania" id="adImageContainer4">
                                            <input type="file" id="adImage4" style="display:none;" name="adPhoto4">
                                        </div>

                                    </div>


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Step 3 Ad Placer Contact Info -->
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#adSteps" href="#stepThreeAdOwnerContactInfo">Contact Info</a></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="stepThreeAdOwnerContactInfo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- Ad Progress bar -->
                <div class="progress">
                    <div id="adProgressBar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:0%">0%
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Ad Submit button -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-4">
                        <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-success" id="adSubmitButton" > <span  class="glyphicon  glyphicon-cog "></span> Post</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
    </div>

</body>
```

I shall be thankful :)

Comment: Just so you know `.css` and `.min.css` contain the same thing, including both of them is redundant. Use `.min.css` if you're concerned about the file size (production) and `.css` on your local development environment.

Comment: Also, did you include `jquery-2.1.3.min.js` and `bootstrap.js`? Bootstrap's Javascript components *will not work* without these.

Comment: @TimLewis thanks it works :)